# How to fix a UnimplementedError in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i get an UnimplementedError in my flutter app and i have not seen any other questions that really helps me with my problem thats why i ask.

i get an UnimplemetedError but i don't know how to fix it properly without having other errors. like "uid is undefined"

so can anyone help me with this error and make the app error free

thank you very much :)

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hetmaantje/utils1/colors.dart';


class todolist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _todolistState createState() => _todolistState();
}

class _todolistState extends State<todolist> {
  String todoTitle = "";
  

  createTodos() {
    @override
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      final User? user = auth.currentUser;
      final uid = user?.uid;

    DocumentReference documentReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid!).doc(todoTitle);

    //Map
    Map<String, String> todos = {"todoTitle": todoTitle};

    documentReference.set(todos).whenComplete(() {
      print("$todoTitle created");
    });
  }

  deleteTodos(item) {
@override
      final User? user = auth.currentUser;
      final uid = user?.uid;
    DocumentReference documentReference =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid!).doc(item);

    documentReference.delete().whenComplete(() {
      print("$item deleted");

    });
  }

  @override
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  @override
  void inputData() {
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user?.uid;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("To-do lijst"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor:  hexStringToColor("fe98a8"),
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  backgroundColor:  hexStringToColor("fe98a8"),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  title: Text("Voeg een nieuwe taak toe"),
                  content: TextField(
                    onChanged: (String value) {
                      todoTitle = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                onPressed:() {
                  createTodos();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text("Add"))
                ],
                );
              });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid!).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshots) {
            if (snapshots.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshots.data?.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                    snapshots.data!.docs[index];
                    return Dismissible(
                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                          deleteTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                        },
                        key: Key(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]),
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 4,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]),
                            trailing: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.delete,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  deleteTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                                }),
                          ),
                        ));
                  });
            } else {
              return Align(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }






  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are format issue on your code. You need to add override over build method and remove bottom build method and close the function properly.

```dart
class todolist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _todolistState createState() => _todolistState();
}

class _todolistState extends State<todolist> {
  String todoTitle = "";

  createTodos() {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user?.uid;

    DocumentReference documentReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid!).doc(todoTitle);

    //Map
    Map<String, String> todos = {"todoTitle": todoTitle};

    documentReference.set(todos).whenComplete(() {
      print("$todoTitle created");
    });
  }

  deleteTodos(item) {
    @override
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user?.uid;
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid!).doc(item);

    documentReference.delete().whenComplete(() {
      print("$item deleted");
    });
  }

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late final User? user = auth.currentUser;
  late final uid = user?.uid;
  late final stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid!).snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("To-do lijst"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: hexStringToColor("fe98a8"),
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  backgroundColor: hexStringToColor("fe98a8"),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  title: Text("Voeg een nieuwe taak toe"),
                  content: TextField(
                    onChanged: (String value) {
                      todoTitle = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          createTodos();
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Text("Add"))
                  ],
                );
              });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: stream,
          builder: (context, snapshots) {
            if (snapshots.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshots.data?.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                        snapshots.data!.docs[index];
                    return Dismissible(
                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                          deleteTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                        },
                        key: Key(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]),
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 4,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]),
                            trailing: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.delete,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  deleteTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                                }),
                          ),
                        ));
                  });
            } else {
              return Align(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: there is still an error in line 97 because uid is now Undefined. and if i want to make it defined it will give me the same error as before. can you help me plss? thanks for your solution

Comment: Can you tell/paste here, the variable or line code on 97?

Comment: it is 94 sorry : stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid!).snapshots(),

Comment: fixed that, it was another  brackets issue, try update snippet, also use variable for stream inside statefulWidget to avoid unnecessary  API call.

Comment: Glad to help, also use code formatter while writing code, it will  make it more readable, also `error lense` extension can help vscode.

Comment: That's exactly what i need Thank you. I think it will help me so much.